# How to kill a process by name?

Tags: delphi, kill-process

How can I kill a process starting from a given process name?

For example: How can I kill `program.exe`?

I've tried the following code which returns the process name starting from a `PID` but it doesn't fit for my needs (In my case I have the process name and want to kill it)

```
function GetPathFromPID(const PID: cardinal): string;
var
  hProcess: THandle;
  path: array[0..MAX_PATH - 1] of char;
begin
  hProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_VM_READ, false, PID);
  if hProcess <> 0 then
    try
      if GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, 0, path, MAX_PATH) = 0 then
        RaiseLastOSError;
      result := path;
    finally
      CloseHandle(hProcess)
    end
  else
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean by "doesn't work"? That is never a valid problem description. Does it give you an error? Do you get unexpected results? Does nothing happen at all? Have you debugged it yet? Or are you wanting to get the process id from the filename? What if there is more than one process for the same executable?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [this](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=266) function in order to kill a process by name:

```
uses
  TlHelp32;

function KillTask(ExeFileName: string): Integer;
const
  PROCESS_TERMINATE = $0001;
var
  ContinueLoop: BOOL;
  FSnapshotHandle: THandle;
  FProcessEntry32: TProcessEntry32;
begin
  Result := 0;
  FSnapshotHandle := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  FProcessEntry32.dwSize := SizeOf(FProcessEntry32);
  ContinueLoop := Process32First(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32);

  while Integer(ContinueLoop) <> 0 do
  begin
    if ((UpperCase(ExtractFileName(FProcessEntry32.szExeFile)) =
      UpperCase(ExeFileName)) or (UpperCase(FProcessEntry32.szExeFile) =
      UpperCase(ExeFileName))) then
      Result := Integer(TerminateProcess(
                        OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE,
                                    BOOL(0),
                                    FProcessEntry32.th32ProcessID),
                                    0));
     ContinueLoop := Process32Next(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32);
  end;
  CloseHandle(FSnapshotHandle);
end;
```

Note:

- There could be more than 1 process having the same name
- `KillTask` function returns the count of the killed processes
- The [page](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=266) where I've found the function says that it works on Windows 9x/ME/2000/XP.
- I've personally tested it on Windows 7/10

Answer (score 1):

work all windows. uses FindWindow unit windows

```
KillTask('c:\my.cmd');

KillTask('caption');

procedure TForm1.KillTask(ExeFileName: string);
var
  H: HWND;
begin //ExeFileName = caption or cmd path
   H := FindWindow(nil, LPCWSTR(ExeFileName));
   if H <> 0 then
    PostMessage(H, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
end;
```

Comment: Doesn't work for ExeFileName

Comment: This isn't killing a process, this is asking nicely a window to close.